# jQuery smooth scrolling not working

Tags: jquery

I've written a script for smooth scrolling on my website, but it doesn't seem to work  but other claim it works. (Using latest chrome version, haven't tried different browsers). Any suggestions what may be the case ? I've linked the script in the html page below.

HTML:

```
<a id="top"></a>
**page content here**
<a href="#top">Go to top</a>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^="#"').click(function() {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        if (target.length == 0) target = $('a[name="' + this.hash.substr(1) + '"]');
        if (target.length == 0) target = $('html');
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top }, 500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me in Chrome 29.0.1547.66 m. http://jsfiddle.net/r6JHh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not appear to be the problem but your selector is not correct :

```
$('a[href^="#"') // Wrong but jQuery appears to deal with it
$('a[href^="#"]') // Right
```

## EDIT

Considering that you use an old version of jQuery (1.2.6 from 2008), it could in fact be the problem :

```
$('a[href^="#"') // jQuery 1.2.6 in your page returns an empty set
$('a[href^="#"]') // Works with 1.2.6 : one anchor element in the set
```

Comment: I don't get it, I literally copied your code and it still doesen't work with mine

Comment: Can you post a url for us to check it live ?

Comment: Sorry about that, I just uploaded it - used it locally. I updated it now, so should work normally

Comment: Haha, no jquery at all this time. Still 1 error : `$ is not defined`

Comment: Why use such an old version on jQuery ? 1.2.6 from 2008

Comment: Selector : see answer

Comment: I used the newest version but tried 1.2.6 to see if it was a problem with the latest version, it doesen't work with either

Comment: Really ? Because I tried your code `$('a[href^="#"')` in your page and it returns an empty set, so the click handler never gets binded to anything. But if you correct the selector `$('a[href^="#"]')` it works, it returns a set of 1 anchor element, the click handler is binded and the smooth scrolling is functional. Did everything in the console in your page.

Answer (score 0):

It may be jQuery version problem, this.hash doesn't work in 1.7.2(As I noticed)

hash is a property that can be found on elements that contain an href attribute/property.

Comment: 'this' is a reference to the anchor element being clicked on, so 'this.hash' has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine in a simple setup, but I have encountered similar problems in Chrome before. Especially if your html is complex. Chrome sometimes doesen't acknowledge that the viewport needs to be redrawn. What I do when this happens is I make a really obvious change to the DOM at each step of the animation and that should force a redraw. Something like this:

```
$("body").toggleClass("redraw");
```

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6JHh/1/) for you.

Maybe it helps, maybe it doesn't :)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but it didn't work either. This is really strange :p